# Alguien sabe como hacer para contar el numero de caracteres de un tipo "str" y que el programa detecte si son mas de 30 caracteres o mas de 12?

Tags: python, string, condiciones

Este es un codigo de ejemplo, mi error es que no se puede combinar un tipo str con un tipo int. Con lo que dice mi pregunta seria en base a usar if, elife y else.

```
cadena = (input("Ingrese una cadena de texto: "))

if cadena > 30:
print("Wow! Mas de 30 caracteres!")

elif cadena.count() > 12 :
print("Bueno, son más de 12 caracteres")

else:
print("Menos de 10 caracteres")
```

Comment: y como todo lenguaje, tiene una funcion [len](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=len#len)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función len sobre la cadena:

```
cadena = (input("Ingrese una cadena de texto: "))

if len(cadena) > 30:
    print("Wow! Mas de 30 caracteres!")
else:
    if len(cadena) > 12:
        print("Bueno, son más de 12 caracteres")
    else:
        print("Menor que 30 y menor que 12 caracteres")
```